# tesseract-ocr-for-php not reading image

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ocr, tesseract

I am using [tesseract-ocr-for-php](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php). I have installed it on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine without any error. I create file with name `test.php` to test the functionality. Below is the code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

include 'TesseractOCR.php';
//$obj = new TesseractOCR('var/www/html/ocr-tesseract/src/text.png');
//var_dump($obj->run());
var_dump (new TesseractOCR('var/www/html/ocr-tesseract/src/text.png'))->run();
//echo dirname(__FILE__);
die('dafs');
```

and the output is

> object(TesseractOCR)#1 (8) { ["image":"TesseractOCR":private]=>
>   string(39) "var/www/html/ocr-tesseract/src/text.png"
>   ["executable":"TesseractOCR":private]=> string(9) "tesseract"
>   ["tessdataDir":"TesseractOCR":private]=> NULL
>   ["userWords":"TesseractOCR":private]=> NULL
>   ["userPatterns":"TesseractOCR":private]=> NULL
>   ["languages":"TesseractOCR":private]=> array(0) { }
>   ["psm":"TesseractOCR":private]=> NULL
>   ["configs":"TesseractOCR":private]=> array(0) { } } Fatal error: Call
>   to a member function run() on null in
>   /var/www/html/ocr-tesseract/src/test.php on line 13

What is wrong I am doing?

i tried with [this](http://hanzratech.in/2015/01/16/ocr-using-tesseract-on-ubuntu-14-04.html) link too. but still same.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

var_dump ((new TesseractOCR('var/www/html/ocr-tesseract/src/text.png'))->run());

Comment: `tvar`  is not i my folder path

Comment: Sorry, by mistake 't' was added.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but you have made a mistake to wrote this sentence. Please check your  sentence and my sentence.